# On site self evaluations, is it OK to answer the questions before the review queue is closed?

Tags: discussion, review, answers, site-evaluation

Related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214761/should-i-improve-posts-that-are-part-of-the-site-self-evaluation-or-wait-until-t) (about fixing spelling errors in nominated questions), but about actually answering one or more of the questions.

It seems that this kind of defeats the purpose of a quality review, at least if you do it properly, but I haven't found anything to verify this. Will I mess anything up if I answer open evaluation review posts?

Sometimes, a new answer will put a thread into an entirely different quality level (hopefully better). If this is OK, is it better to post the answer(s) soon after the queues open, or wait until nearer the end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We encourage people to edit posts under review if they need it, and I don't see how answering would be any different.

Basically, if you see a post that could be improved, do it! These reviews still receive human oversight and any action that raises the overall quality of the post is welcome at any time.